# In BioShock 1 I can't get past the first loading screen

Tags: ps3, technical-issues, bioshock

I'm playing on PS3 and can only get through Andrew Ryan's first speech, after that the game black screens every time without fail.  Is this a thing that happens often?  How do I get through this?

Comment: Did you buy the game brand new?  Sounds like a broken disk or something.

Comment: Yes this one is new, it also happened to the used copy I bought before this one.

Comment: Okay, so if you've tried two disks, and they both do the same thing, then chances are very good it's your PS3.  Can you try the game in a friend's system?

Comment: Not for a while :/

Comment: When the game black screens, do you have to force restart, which the PS3 complains about when it reboots? I had a similar problem and the PS3's laser needed to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you had an error while installing the game.

1. In the game section of the xmb go to the game installation folder and completely delete the game.
2. Put the disc in, and install it again.

If this doesn't work then you can try restoring the file system, but I'd only do that as a last resort.

1. delete the game again, cut off the console, and wait a minute before cutting it back on. If you have a fat model ps3 hold down the power button until you hear a third beep. If you have a slim model it may work that way or you may have to hold the power until the console goes off, then hold the power button again it will beep, beep again, and then double beep. At the double beep let go of the button.  This puts the console in recovery mode.
2. Choose the option to restore the file system, and wait.